# Write multiple dataframes to multiple sheets in excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have 4 different programs that read 4 different types of csv files to get the data in the same format. My goal is to export dataframes from each program into a single excel workbook onto 4 seperate sheets. Each time I write a dataframe to excel it overwrites the data that was just exported there.

this is the code I have which is the same for each program:

```
rowPos = 1
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f"Y:\HedgeFundRecon\JAron\Output\JAronOutput.xlsx", datetime_format='mm/dd/yy') as writer:
        for item in df_list:
            item.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='JAron', startrow=rowPos)
            rowPos += (len(item) + 2)
```

I changed the code to this to check if the file does not exists then just write to the file, but if it does exist then overwrite the sheet:

```
rowPos = 1
    if(os.path.exists(path)):
        with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace', datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:
            for item in df_list:
                item.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='JAron', startrow=rowPos)
                rowPos += (len(item) + 2)
    else:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl', mode='w', date_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:   
            for item in df_list:
                item.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='JAron', startrow=rowPos)
                rowPos += (len(item) + 2)
```

How would I alter this code to stop the data from being overwritten? I tried putting the mode to append but xlsxwriter does not support that. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want 4 separate sheets, why is `sheet_name` constant?

Comment: @BigBen Each Program exports dataframes to the same workbook, but different sheet name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

> I tried putting the mode to append but `xlsxwriter` does not support that

Try specifying `engine='openpyxl'` and install it if necessary with `pip install openpyxl`.

Using `xlsxwriter` in append mode gives the following result:

```
ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!
```

---

You have to use this 2 options with [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

- `mode='a'` to avoid to override your workbook
- `if_sheet_exists='replace'` to replace an existing sheet (not mandatory)

```
rowPos = 1
with pd.ExcelWriter(f"Y:\HedgeFundRecon\JAron\Output\JAronOutput.xlsx", 
                    datetime_format='mm/dd/yy',
                    mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    for item in df_list:
        item.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='JAron', startrow=rowPos)
        rowPos += (len(item) + 2)
```

Take care if two of your scripts try to write simultaneously the same file.

Comment: that worked for the most part. is if_sheet_exists supposed to overwrite the existing sheet? because it is not for me

Comment: Does it raise an exception when you use `if_sheet_exists='replace'` in append mode?

Comment: no. when I run the script it works fine. the second time I run the script the data is disappearing instead of overwriting. I updated the question with new code

Comment: Scroll down (again and again or use Find Ctrl+F). Replace `if_sheet_exists='replace'` with `if_sheet_exists='overlay'`